# What will happen if an attribute is used in program without enabled and binding a buffer?

Tags: google-chrome, webgl

Recently, when I reading the webgl spec. I have a question about below, since my program has randomly error on chrome browser due to it:

What will happen if an attribute is used in program without binding a buffer and enabled during a call to drawArrays or drawElements?

The spec only says that:

> If a vertex attribute is enabled as an array, a buffer is bound to
>   that attribute, but the attribute is not consumed by the current
>   program, then regardless of the size of the bound buffer, it will not
>   cause any error to be generated during a call to drawArrays or
>   drawElements.
>
> If a vertex attribute is enabled as an array via
>   enableVertexAttribArray but no buffer is bound to that attribute via
>   bindBuffer and vertexAttribPointer, then calls to drawArrays or
>   drawElements will generate an INVALID_OPERATION error

Can anyone help me on this??

Comment: So, what do you actually want? As the spec says it's not valid to enable attribute array without a buffer bound to it.

Comment: @TwilightSun yes, if my sprogram will use that attribute, but this attribute is not bound to a buffer and hasn't been enabled. The result will randomly be fail and success on chrome on my HTC One. But it will always success on firefox browser on HTC One. I am very curious about this behavior. BTW. On SamSung Note2 it will always successful on both chrome and firefox.

Comment: The version of chrome and firefox on HTC One and SamSung are exactly same.

Comment: Does this test pass on both browsers? https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/conformance/attribs/gl-disabled-vertex-attrib.html

Comment: The spec document only give an description on how the APIs should be like, but the real implementation varies between different vendors. Especially on how they treat errors.

Comment: @gman, yes, it always same. Actually I found a test case in webgl conformance test suite, it is almost same with my situation.
https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/conformance/more/functions/drawElements.html
It will randomly fails on chrome on HTC One.

Comment: @TwilightSun You mean the same version of chrome has different behavior on different devices since they have different vendors???

Comment: @gman You can check the test case, that the shader has used attributes Normal and Tex without enabled and binding to a buffer. That's the case I mentioned in my ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second paragraph says you'll get an error, always, if you enable an attribute but don't bind a buffer.

There's 4 possibilities

1. You have an attribute enabled with a buffer bound and that attribute is used by the current shader program.

   In this case the buffer must be large enough to handle whatever you try to draw. In other words if you have a buffer with 3 vertices but you ask WebGL to draw 4 vertices you'll get an error. Or if you call `gl.drawElements` and one of your indices is greater than 2 you'll get an error.
2. You have an attribute enabled with a buffer bound and that attribute is **NOT** used by the current shader program.

   In this case there will be no error even if the buffer is not large enough because the buffer is not used.
3. You have an attribute enabled with **NO BUFFER** bound.

   In this case you'll get an error, always.
4. You have an attribute disabled

   In this case it will use the value supplied by calling `gl.vertexAttrib4f` or one of its variants.

The 2 paragraphs you quoted from the spec cover cases 2 and 3 above.